# Simple application like login page

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I am new to iPhone application making, and I am trying to create a simple page -- it's like a login page. I have a SQLite database which has user names and passwords.
My GUI is like this: I have two text fields, User Name and Password, and also a Login button.

I found code for creating the login page, but it doesn't work. Check out the code below, see whether I am going wrong. It says "Too many arguments to function 'isEqualToString:'"

```
-(void)checkindatabase
{
    NSString *txtUsername = @"";
    NSString *txtPassword = @"";
    NSString *sqlStatement = @"";
    NSString *direct = [[NSString alloc]init] ;
    NSString *dbPath = [direct stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"journeymapper.db3"];


    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {

        sqlStatement = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select Username='%@',Password='%@' from UserInformation",txtuser.text,txtpass.text];
        //[sql UTF8String];
            //NSLog(@"'%s'",[sql UTF8String]);
        sqlite3_stmt *statment;
        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {
             while (sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW)
             {
                 txtUsername = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment,1)] retain];
                 txtPassword = [[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(statment, 2)] retain];

             }


        }
                sqlite3_finalize(statment);
                sqlite3_close(database);
        if([txtUsername isEqualToString:@"%@",_Textuser]&&[txtPassword isEqualToString:@"%@",_Textpass])
            { 
                UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:nil message:@"You are  vaild user" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alert show];
                [alert release];
            }


    }

}

-(IBAction)login
{
    [self checkindatabase]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of:

```
[txtUsername isEqualToString:@"%@",_Textuser]
```

use:

```
[txtUsername isEqualToString:_Textuser]
```

or:

```
[txtUsername isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_Textuser]]
```

As the error said, you have too many (2) arguments where the method `-isEqualToString:` expects only one.

Comment: I want to check bout _Textuser and _TextPassword how can do this

Comment: Thanks It work but doesn't show me alter view. Even I enter the right username and password.What's the problem now

Comment: It's not going into the Condition .It 1st check.if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) then it go on to the if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(datvabase, [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) after that  The problem here arise it not check the condition  while (sqlite3_step(statment) ==SQLITE_ROW)where{txtusername&txtPassword}it directly jump onto the sqlite3_finalize(statment); what was the porblem i didn't  understand dear.

Answer (score 0):

you are passing format in `isEqualToString:`

you can do it as you can do it as

```
[txtUsername isEqualToString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_Textuser]];
```

Comment: saabnib Thanks It work but doesn't show me alter view. Even I enter the right username and password.What's the problem now

Comment: just NSLog both values before if statement and check for console are they same.

Comment: It's not going into the Condition .It 1st check if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK) then it go on the  if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(datvabase, [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], -1, &statment, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) But The problem here is the it check the condition  while (sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW) where my txtusername & txtPassword it directly jump onto the sqlite3_finalize(statment); what was the porblem dear i didn't understand

Comment: its mean that now row in database means your database is empty

Comment: I have one enter in my databasse which has value (user name" harish" and password "harish" ;

Comment: change this  sqlStatement = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select Username='%@',Password='%@' from UserInformation",txtuser.text,txtpass.text];
 to sqlStatement = @"select * from UserInformation";

Comment: I didn'st download the sqlite .i am creating database into sql2008 by giving .db3  extension after that  i drag this into the my project is that proper .

Comment: DB connect  succesfully open but when go on this condition if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database,[sql UTF8String],-1,&statment,NULL) == SQLITE_OK) after going this it directly jumped out from the loop.it will not check if(sqlite3_step(statment) == SQLITE_ROW) { this condition where i have my UIAlertView //when user right username & password }

Comment: have you changed your sqlStatement as i mentioned above if yes then run it in firfox sqlite plugin and check for result, actually you have to debug the procedure is as i mentioned above.

Comment: can you please send me the example sample code for trying to get this solve